# Running python manage.py shell i get Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to get PostgreSQL to work with psycopg2, and I have run into error after error.  Every time I find a fix to the current error, a new error will appear.  I installed PostgreSQL, I finally was able to install psycopg2 successfully, and I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0. I changed line 243 of Python27/Lib/distilus/msvc9compiler.py from

```
toolskey = "VS%0f0COMNTOOLS" % version
```

to

toolskey = "VS90COMNTOOLS"

by following http://web.archive.org/web/20101221084639/http://nukeit.org/compile-python-2-7-packages-with-visual-studio-2010-express/.  Note: I also tried VS100COMNTOOLS as was used in the guide, but I figured since I had version 9.0 of visual studio, that would be what I should use.  I also added the system variable

```
variable=VS90COMNTOOLS , value=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools.
```

The only reason I even tried this was to take care of the last error in my continuous chain of errors, which occurred when trying to install psycopg2:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I've been trying to make the database switch from SQLite to PostgreSQL for a few days now, without any luck.  I don't see why this would be so difficult to do.  I would really appreciate some help.  I'm pretty new to Django, Python, and any programming.  I've searched the other answers, and that is how I've gotten past the first several answers, but none ever seem to end with a fix.  The only output I get is the error message displayed in the title.  I was attempting to go back to chapter 5 of the Django Book to make sure I had my configuration set up correctly, but apparently I don't because I cant even run python manage.py shell.

Thank you to anyone who can finally help me with this.

Comment: Are you sure that VS installed without errors? Its bit** to install properly, and missing stuff can mean that you either need full VS or that it was installed with errors. (Maybe you can use VM for checking that if you do not want to mess with your system)

Comment: The psycopg2 download page links to pre-compiled Windows builds. Is there any reason you're not using them, given the nightmare that compiling software on Windows is?

Comment: I didn't really understand what the pre-compiled builds are.  I am very new to everything.  I just started learning a few months ago and this is my first project attempt without any formal education.  The extent of my knowledge is basically learnpythonthehardway, codecademy, and the djangobook.  I still don't really have a good grasp on a lot of stuff and don't understand what the difference between what I was doing before and what I did with the pre-compiled builds - only that now it works.  I would be receptive to an explanation to help understand, but either way at least it works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to compile *psycopg2* from the source on *Windows* is probably going to be very tricky. I recommend the solution I use which is to install the pre-compiled *psycopg2* Windows packages graciously provided by the *Stickpeople Project* from here: http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/.

Comment: Thanks.  I finally got everything working.  What exactly do the pre-compiled packages do?

Comment: The pre-compiled (or binary) packages, in contrast with the source packages, have the non-Python components (usually C/C++ bindings for a  C/C++ library, in this case *psycopg2* uses *libpq* from PostgreSQL to communicate with the database) already compiled to binaries for the target platform, so you just need to install instead of needing to compile as you do with the non-pure Python source packages. Note that this binary packages are however always specific for a given interpreter version and OS.

Comment: Makes more sense now.  I appreciate it.